# How to compare the multi dimensional array with parallel row and column index in magento?

Tags: php, arrays, compare

**Hi Please run my code:** Please see my expected output . how to moderate my code for my expected result.

```
<?php
$arrayA=array(array("id" => 8, "name" => "test1"),  
            array("id" => 4, "name" => "test2"),  
            array("id" => 4, "name" => "test3")  
);
$arrayB=array(array("id" => 3, "domain_name" => "www.test.com","activation_key" =>"ADKLJ"),
            array("id" => 4,  "domain_name" => "www.yahoomail.com","activation_key" =>"LKLJ"),
            array("id" => 4, "domain_name" => "www.gmail.com","activation_key" =>"OLOLJ")           
);

//$places=Array();
$i=0;
foreach($arrayA as $itemA)
{
    $match=0;

    foreach($arrayB as $itemB)
    {
        if($itemA["id"]==$itemB["id"])
        {
            $arrayA[$i]["domain_name"]=$itemB["domain_name"];
            $arrayA[$i]["activation_key"]=$itemB["activation_key"];
            $match=1;
        }
    }
    if($match==0)
    {
            $arrayA[$i]["domain_name"]="";
            $arrayA[$i]["activation_key"]="";
    }
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayA);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

**Output**

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => test1
            [domain_name] => 
            [activation_key] => 
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => test2
        [domain_name] => www.gmail.com
        [activation_key] => OLOLJ
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => test3
        [domain_name] => www.gmail.com
        [activation_key] => OLOLJ
    )
```

)

**But my expected Output is**

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [name] => test1
            [domain_name] => 
            [activation_key] => 
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => test2
        [domain_name] => www.yahoomail.com
        [activation_key] => LKLJ
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => test3
        [domain_name] => www.gmail.com
        [activation_key] => OLOLJ
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Try following way

```
<?php
$arrayA=array(array("id" => 8, "name" => "test1"),  
            array("id" => 4, "name" => "test2"),  
            array("id" => 4, "name" => "test3")  
);
$arrayB=array(array("id" => 3, "domain_name" => "www.test.com","activation_key" =>"ADKLJ"),
            array("id" => 4,  "domain_name" => "www.yahoomail.com","activation_key" =>"LKLJ"),
            array("id" => 4, "domain_name" => "www.gmail.com","activation_key" =>"OLOLJ")           
);

//$places=Array();
$i=0;
foreach($arrayA as $key => $itemA)
{
    $match=0;
    $itemB = $arrayB[$key]; 
        if($itemA["id"]==$itemB["id"])
        {
            $arrayA[$i]["domain_name"]=$itemB["domain_name"];
            $arrayA[$i]["activation_key"]=$itemB["activation_key"];
            $match=1;
        }
    if($match==0)
    {
            $arrayA[$i]["domain_name"]="";
            $arrayA[$i]["activation_key"]="";
    }
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayA);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Working Sample: http://codepad.org/mrBqqeli

Comment: Your most welcome. it's good to accept answers for you. it increase changes to get more answers for your question

Answer (score 0):

```
// store all activated domains
$activated = array();

foreach($arrayA as $key => $itemA)
{
    $match=0;

    foreach($arrayB as $itemB)
    {
        if($itemA["id"]==$itemB["id"] && !in_array($itemB["domain_name"],$activated))
        {
            $arrayA[$key]["domain_name"]=$itemB["domain_name"];
            $arrayA[$key]["activation_key"]=$itemB["activation_key"];
            $match=1;
            $activated[] = $itemB["domain_name"];
            break;
        }
    }
    if($match==0)
    {
            $arrayA[$key]["domain_name"]="";
            $arrayA[$key]["activation_key"]="";
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrayA);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: your welcome, when a question is solved you will see a green mark along reply, click that to accept answer, if you will accept answers you will get more help in future.